# Golang profiling - top10 shows only one line with 100%

Tags: go, profiling

I try to profiling my go library, to find out what is the cause of being so much slower than same thing in c++.

I have simple benchmark

```
func BenchmarkFile(t *testing.B) {
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", TMP_FILE_PREFIX)

    fw, err := NewFile(tmpFile.Name())
    text := []byte("testing")
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, err = fw.Write(text)
    }
    fw.Close()
}
```

NewFile return my custom Writer which encodes data to our binary representation, even compress them, and write to file system.

Running `go test -bench . -memprofile mem.out -cpuprofile cpu.out` I get

```
PASS
BenchmarkFile-16    2000000000           0.20 ns/op
ok      .../writer/iowriter 9.074s
```

Than analysing it

```
# go tool pprof cpu.out 
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands)
(pprof) top10
930ms of 930ms total (  100%)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     930ms   100%   100%      930ms   100%  
(pprof)
```

I even try to write example.go app which is using my writer, and add `pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)` as is shown in http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs but with same result.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I determine what is bottleneck of my lib?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using "i < 1000"? Benchmarks must use the b.N field or they won't give correct results, as each benchmark function is potentially called multiple times with different values of b.N.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok it's easy, I miss to add binary to go tool pprof, si it has to be

```
# go tool pprof write cpu.out 
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands)
(pprof) top10
7.02s of 7.38s total (95.12%)
Dropped 14 nodes (cum <= 0.04s)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 32 (cum >= 0.19s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     6.55s 88.75% 88.75%      6.76s 91.60%  syscall.Syscall
    ...
```

and when using benchmark tests, binary is created there and using it gives same result.

Comment: Can you please clarify this answer?  It's unclear what your solution was or whether it worked.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. "I miss to add binary to go tool pprof"
so it has to be: "go tool pprof write cpu.out"
and after this command, you can see the output, so it worked..

Answer (score 1):

To expand on sejvolnd's answer:

`pprof` needs the binary that actually generated `cpu.out` file as a first argument.

So you need to run the command as `go tool pprof <go binary of your program> <generaged profiling output file>`

e.g. `go tool pprof go_binary cpu.pprof`